Matlab LU factorization code
I have typed this code to perform the LU factorization for $Ax=b$ when we are given matrix $A$ and $x=(1,1,1)^T$. My code is below
function results = lu_factorization_and_verify()
% Known exact solution x
x_exact = [1; 1; 1]; % Corresponding to the solution x_ex = (1, 1, 1)^T

for k = 0:9
    epsilon = 10^(-k);
    
    % Define matrix A
    A = [2, -2, 0; 
         epsilon - 2, 2, 0; 
         0, -1, 3];
     
    % Define vector b using the known solution
    b = A * x_exact; % Calculate b = Ax
    
    % LU factorization
    [L, U, P] = lu(A);
    
    % Solve Ly = Pb
    y = L \ (P * b);
    
    % Solve Ux = y
    x_computed = U \ y;
    
    % Store the result
    results{k + 1} = x_computed;  % Store computed result
    
    % Calculate the error
    error = norm(x_computed - x_exact); % L2 norm of the error
    fprintf('For k=%d (epsilon=10^-%d), computed x: [%f; %f; %f], error: %e\n', ...
            k, k, x_computed(1), x_computed(2), x_computed(3), error);
end

However when I run this code $P$ should return the identity and instead I am getting
\begin{align}
P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &0 \\ 0 &0 &1 \\ 0 &1 &0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Is there an issue in my code that I am missing?

Have you tried to explain the phenomenon? Do tell us what you have tried :)

To add on the previous comment, what makes you think that $P$ should be identity?

"Why is my code producing the wrong answer?" This is not a forum for debugging user code with no additional context.

In the problem I was given I am told to verify that my answer was not affected by rounding errors. I thought this implied that no permutation has taken place and thus P would be the identity. I thought there was an issue with how I entered matrix A but I have not been able to figure that out. @Korf

I wasnt sure if it was a problem with a math component or if it was a coding issue @whpowell96
